# Automatically run css transition

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Do you have any idea on running the css transition automatically when the user enters our website without element:hover, element:active and without using the onload in jquery? Btw we are using transition not animation in css sir.

Just like this: `https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Using_CSS_transitions`

Comment: You want to change something without changing something?  What for?  All you have to do is change a property with JavaScript when the page loads, but you said you don't want to do that.

Comment: Then *do* use a CSS animation. That’s what they’re for.